# GET запросом передать картинку

Tags: php

Задача стоит так: передать картинку на сервер, не заходя на сайт и не загружая через POST и бла-бла-бла.

Вопрос: можно ли как нибудь передать картинку на сервер не используя метод POST?

Вопрос2: например если передавать через GET используя кодировку base64, то там есть символы ( а именно =) который портит гет запрос, и сколько по объему я смогу передать.

Кто нибудь костылял так?) есть идеи по этому поводу? может еще кодировки есть?

Comment: Объём зависит от настроек конкретного сервера, но в любом случае это единицы килобайт. Думаю, больше 3 уже не получится в общем случае.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ограничение на длину url 4 килобайта, если не ошибаюсь.

Есть сомнительная идея пихать части картинки в кастомные http-заголовки (в том же base64, например). Не помню, есть ли ограничение на суммарный объём заголовков.

А зачем вообще это надо?

Comment: В RFC вроде бы ограничений нет. Но они могут быть у сервера. Например, в апаче см. LimitRequestLine и LimitRequestFieldSize.

Answer (score -4):

Для кодировния данных для query string существует специальная функция `urlencode()`.
Но из коротких штанишек пора, пора уже вырастать.
И делать не то что "проще", а что правильнее. То есть - загружать либо постом, либо вовсе предназначенными для передачи файлов средствами, например FTP